# Listbox is not able to show items based on another list

Tags: ms-access

I am currently trying to set up a GUI frontend for easier querying for colleagues.

I have tried researching and following instructions from various sources but still not able to make it work.

I have two lists.

1) This is the row source query for the first list(List0):

```
SELECT Test_Case_ID.Test_Case_Unique_ID, Test_Case_ID.Test_Case_Description
FROM Test_Case_ID
ORDER BY Test_Case_ID.[Test_Case_Description];
```

2) This is for the second list(List2):

```
SELECT Reference_ID.Reference
FROM Test_Case_ID INNER JOIN (Reference_ID INNER JOIN Test_Result 
    ON Reference_ID.Reference_Unique_ID = Test_Result.Reference_Unique_ID) 
ON Test_Case_ID.Test_Case_Unique_ID = Test_Result.Test_Case_Unique_ID
WHERE (((Test_Case_ID.Test_Case_Description)=[Forms]![Form1]![List0]));
```

I have a an event procedure for List0:

```
Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()
Forms![Form1]![List2].Requery
End Sub
```

However, there are no outputs on List2 even after clicking on items in List0. Can I have some advice to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Most likely the value of List0 is ID not Description.

Comment: Yeah, Indeed, the value of it was ID. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check that the **bound column** of your list box `List0` corresponds to your `Test_Case_Description` field.

With the form open and populated with data, you can also run a number of tests 'manually' by creating a separate query containing the SQL for your list box row source and verifying whether or not it returns any results:

```sql
select 
    reference_id.reference
from 
    test_case_id inner join 
    (
        reference_id inner join test_result 
        on reference_id.reference_unique_id = test_result.reference_unique_id
    ) 
    on test_case_id.test_case_unique_id = test_result.test_case_unique_id
where 
    test_case_id.test_case_description = [forms]![form1]![list0]
```

You can also use a query with the following SQL code to test the value returned by `[forms]![form1]![list0]` and ensure that it returns the value that you expect for use in your selection criteria:

```sql
select 
    t.test_case_description,
    [forms]![form1]![list0] as listboxvalue,
    t.test_case_description = [forms]![form1]![list0] as testmatch
from 
    test_case_id t
```